# Get attribute value from XML DOM List

Tags: php, xml, dom, xml-parsing

I have an XML file (below) that I am trying to parse with PHP.

```
<content>
  <row label='DEV'>
   <cell href="exUrl('URL')"  status='0'>12345</cell>
   <cell href="exUrl('URL')"  status='1'>12345</cell>
   <cell href="exUrl('URL')"  status='1'>12345</cell>
   <cell href="exUrl('URL')"  status='1'>12345</cell>
   <cell href="exUrl('URL')"  status='1'>12345</cell>
  </row>
  <row label='DEV2'>
   <cell href="exUrl('URL')"  status='1'>56789</cell>
   <cell href="exUrl('URL')"  status='1'>56789</cell>
   <cell href="exUrl('URL')"  status='1'>56789</cell>
   <cell href="exUrl('URL')"  status='1'>56789</cell>
   <cell href="exUrl('URL')"  status='0'>56789</cell>
  </row>
 </content>
```

I'm currently using PHP to sum a number of 'rows' from an XML document (example below).

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$html = $dom->loadHTMLFile("XML.xml");
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$tables = $dom->getElementsByTagName('content');
$rows = $tables->item(0)->getElementsByTagName('row');
foreach ($rows as $row)
{
    $cols = $row->getElementsByTagName('cell');
    $totalValues += $cols->item(4)->nodeValue;
}
```

I've updated the for loop to include an if statement to check the status value, however this doesn't seem to be working.

```
foreach ($rows as $row)
{
    $cols = $row->getElementsByTagName('cell');
    $totalValues += $cols->item(4)->nodeValue;
    if(($cols->item(4)->getElementsByTagName('status')->nodeValue) == 0) {
        $flag = 0;
    }
}
```

Can anyone assist with what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: `$cols->item(4)->getAttribute('status') == 0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`status` is an attribute node, not an element node. Here are several ways to get the value. The easiest is just to read it from the element node:

```
if ($cols->item(4)->getAttribute('status') == 0) { ...
```

Or you can fetch the attribute node and read its value.

```
if ($cols->item(4)->getAttributeNode('status')->value == 0) { ...
```

Last, you can optimize you loops using Xpath and use an Xpath expression to set `$flag`.

```
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->load($xmlFile);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);

$total = 0;
foreach ($xpath->evaluate('/content/row/cell[5]') as $cell) {
  $total += $cell->nodeValue;
}

$flag = $xpath->evaluate('count(/content/row/cell[5][@status=0]) > 0');

var_dump($total, $flag);
```

The first Xpath expression `/content/row/cell[5]` fetches all `cell` element nodes, that have the fifth position inside `/content/row`.

In the second experession that list is filtered by the value of the `status` attribute. The `cell` nodes with the `status` 0 are counted. If that count is greater then 0 the expression return `true`.